# Can I use Send-MailMessage cmdlet with a CRT certificate?

Tags: powershell, ssl, tls1.2

I have this code:

```
Clear-Host
$file = "c:\Mail-content.txt"

if (test-path $file)
{
    $from = "afgarciact@gmail.com"
    $to = "<slopez@comfama.com.co>","<carloscu@comfama.com.co>"
    $pc = get-content env:computername
    $subject = "Test message " + $pc
    $smtpserver ="172.16.201.55"
    $body = Get-Content $file | Out-String

    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls,TLS11,TLS12'
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { return $true }

    foreach ($recipient in $to)
    {
        Write-Host "Sent to $to"
        Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpserver -UseSsl -From $from -To $recipient -Subject $subject -BodyAsHtml $body -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Configuración"
}
```

I want to know if I can use a CRT certificated instead of setting `ServerCertificateValidationCallback = TRUE`.

This is a test environment.

The CRT certificate was already added to the SMTP server.

Comment: [Related](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: But I am using PowerShell. =/

Comment: PowerShell can utilize .Net classes. What do you think `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is?